# On Windows, Using C++ is it possible to programmatically obtain a string name for the Assembly from a given function ptr

Tags: c++, windows, function, debugging, dll

If you set a breakpoint in the debugger over a function ptr, you will see the name of the assembly included in the inspector panel. This seems to work for all function objects including lambdas.

You may see something like this;

```
Func=0x00FF00FF00{UE4Editor-Game.dll!<lambda_4b5336d9060965465490645>::<lambda_invoker_cdecl>}
```

**Question; How would one programmatically obtain a string containing the assembly information given here, using the function pointer `Func` and functions that are available a Windows development environment?**

For the given example I would call something like this;

```
const char* details = GetFunctionAssemblyString(Func);
```

The most important part I would like to obtain is this; `UE4Editor-Game.dll` However the full string might also be interesting...

This is for development tools only, and not-intended to be cross platform, so using windows specific functions is acceptable. I have access to the debug database .pdb.

Cheers

Comment: Related answer on MSDN:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05b01fb8-50ab-4f97-b500-5a28c383198e/function-name-from-function-pointer?forum=vcgeneral

Answer (score 1):

Note that 'assembly' is a term that is limited to .net, it indicates an image file (whether exe or dll or otherwise) that has attached metadata. For native contexts the analogous term is 'module', a module may or may not have symbol names available but is likely not going to have more than that in the usual case. Note that there may possibly be debugging information but that can be removed and the module will continue to work, the same is not the case if the metadata were removed from a .net assembly.

All of that being said, you can use the Debug Help Library to get as much information about a native process as is available. Note that comments in SymInitialize make it sound like it is not feasible for a process to load information about itself. Once you have initialized dbghelp for a particular process you could use SymFromAddr to get the name associated with a particular address and then SymGetModuleInfo64 to get information for the module containing that address.

Comment: Of course it's not the word that is limited to .NET, but the peculiar meaning.  Also note that .NET assemblies don't have to correspond 1:1 to files, although they often do.